# Cannot access cordova's SQL-lite storage plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building a simple app using Cordova and AnglerJS, for the database works I decided to use the [cordova-sqlite-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage). Using Cordova's CLI command `cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git` I was able to install the plugin. But when I try to use it I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined application.js:6

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "database.db", location: 2});
});
```

I am suspecting that the plugin itself/installation wasn't correct, are there any farther steps than using the `cordova plugin add ...` ?!

Comment: Do you get that error on your desktop browser or on the device? Also I assume the above JavaScript is just a combined snippet from multiple files?

Comment: I am using Intel XDK Emulation/debugging application (IT'S AWESOME). And yes the snippet is from multiple files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Cordova/PhoneGap [litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin open and use sqlite databases only on:

- Android
- iOS
- Windows Universal(8.1)  // **Not Windows and Browser**
- Amazon Fire-OS
- WP(7/8)

with HTML5/Web SQL API.

This plugin in Chrome or Firefox does not work.

For example, for Android devices, if you have SQLite file "database.db" in your project folder [ mobileapp\www\ ] to connect database file just:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "database.db", createFromLocation: 1});
```

Some simple code:

```
db.transaction(function(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('select * from TABLENAME;', [], function(tx, res)
    {
        console.log(res.rows);   
    }, 
    function(e){
        console.log("error: "+e.message);
    });
});
```

More informations:  [litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage Docs](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#cordovaphonegap-sqlite-storage-adapter)